# How to keep drawer menu open after item selection?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I have used drawer menu from `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` for my xamarin application. Currently when I click each item in the drawer list the drawer layout closes automatically. I don't remember that I have set up anywhere that I want to close the layout after selection! If this is the default behavior please tell me where can I say I want to keep it open after I select an Item?

Comment: do you want to lock it or only close it when the user slides it to the left?

Comment: @AhmadHammoud I want to keep it open after user touches an item but the user should be able to close it by sliding it or touching the menu button. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: did you find any answer, i wish to achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

In the NavigationDrawerFragment class

just comment the line where it closes the drawer after item selection

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        //mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
}
```